# Activity has leaked IntentReceiver that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?

Tags: android, service

I am using a Service to get updates from the location, it's NOT an IntentService, but the log says that **Activity has leaked IntentReceiver that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?**
I don't use a Receiver, so I don't register or unregister. Then, What's the matter with this?

I paste my code for the Service:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class UpdateService2 extends Service {

    private LocationManager locManager;
    private LocationListener locListener;
    private Location loc;
    public static int UPDATE_TIME   = 30000;
    public static long MAX_TIME     = 600000;
    public static long waited = 0;
    boolean active = true;
    String TAG = "UpdateService2";
    Thread myThread;
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBind");
        return null;
    }

    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MyConstants.MY_PREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = prefs.edit();
        startGettingLocation();

        Log.d("UpdateService","Thread - active:"+active+", maxTime: "+MAX_TIME);
        myThread = new Thread() {
            public void run(){
                Log.d("UpdateService","run");
                try {
                    waited = 0;
                    Log.d("UpdateService","Thread - active:"+active+", maxTime: "+MAX_TIME+", waited: "+waited);
                    while(active && (waited < MAX_TIME)) {
                        sleep(10000);
                        if(active) {
                            waited += 10000;
                            Log.d("UpdateService","Thread update: "+waited/1000+" seg");
                        }
                    }
                } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                    Log.d("UpdateService","Exception: "+e.toString());
                } finally {
                    interrupt();
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        active = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        myThread.start();
        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
    }

    private void startGettingLocation(){
        try {
            locListener = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    updatePosition(location);
                    Log.d("UpdateService","Update location - Lat:"+location.getLatitude()+", Lon:"+location.getLongitude());
                }
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){
                }
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){
                }
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
                }
            };
            locManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, UPDATE_TIME, 0, locListener);
            loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            if (loc != null) {
                updatePosition(loc);
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("UpdateService", e.toString());
        }
    }

    private void updatePosition(Location loc) {
        if(loc != null) {
            Double dLat = loc.getLatitude();
            Double dLon = loc.getLatitude();
            editor.putInt(MyConstants.PREFERENCES_LAT, dLat.intValue());
            editor.putInt(MyConstants.PREFERENCES_LON, dLon.intValue());
            editor.commit();
        }
    }

}
```

Then, the call from the activity onCreate is like this:

```
msgIntent = new Intent(this, UpdateService2.class);
startService(msgIntent);
```

And the call from the onDestroy is like this:

```
stopService(msgIntent);
```

Comment: Please reduce your code to the relevant parts if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "my" solution (it really comes from here: [Alarms](http://www.carlos-garcia.es/tutoriales/android-alarmas-alarmmanager.php)):

On manifest, I register my broadcast receiver:

```
<!-- Register BroadcastReceiver -->  
<receiver android:name="com.example.MyReceiver"/>
```

This is the implementation of the receiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  
        MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation(context);
        myLocation.getLocation();
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(MyConstants.MY_PREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        User.myLat =  (double) prefs.getInt(MyConstants.PREFERENCES_LAT, 0);
        User.myLon =  (double) prefs.getInt(MyConstants.PREFERENCES_LON, 0);
        User.isValidPosition = prefs.getBoolean(MyConstants.PREFERENCES_VALID, false);

        //TEST
        Toast.makeText(context, "Testing alarm onReceive - Lat:"+User.myLat/1E6
        +", Long:"+User.myLon/1E6+", isValid:"+User.isValidPosition, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        Log.d("MyReceiver","Lat:"+User.myLat+", Long:"+User.myLon+", isValid:"+User.isValidPosition);
        }

    }
```

The constants that I use (in another class):

```
public class MyConstants {
    public static String MY_PREFERENCES = "MyPreferences";
    public static String PREFERENCES_LAT = "lat";   
    public static String PREFERENCES_LON = "lon";   
    public static String PREFERENCES_VALID = "isValid";
    public static final int ALARM_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
}
```

The class MyLocation, wich is the one that I call from the activity:

```
public class MyLocation {
private LocationManager locManager;
private LocationListener locListener;
private Location loc;
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
private Context context;
private String TAG = "MyLocation";
private int UPDATE_TIME = 0;

public MyLocation(Context context){
    this.context = context;
    prefs = this.context.getSharedPreferences(MyConstants.MY_PREFERENCES,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = prefs.edit();
}

public void getLocation(){
    //Register to get updates of the location
    locListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    updatePosition(location);
    Log.d(TAG,"Update location - Lat:"+location.getLatitude()+", Lon:"+location.getLongitude());                                
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider){

}
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider){

}
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){

}
};
    startGettingLocation();
    locManager.removeUpdates(locListener);
}

private void startGettingLocation(){
    try {
        locManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, UPDATE_TIME, 0, locListener);
        loc = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if (loc != null) {
        updatePosition(loc);
    }
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG, e.toString());       
    }
}

private void updatePosition(Location loc) {
if(loc != null) {
    Double dLat = loc.getLatitude()*1E6;
    Double dLon = loc.getLongitude()*1E6;
    editor.putInt(MyConstants.PREFERENCES_LAT, dLat.intValue());
    editor.putInt(MyConstants.PREFERENCES_LON, dLon.intValue());
    editor.putBoolean(MyConstants.PREFERENCES_VALID, true);
    editor.commit();
} 
}

}
```

I put the references of latitude and longitude in the preferences to have easy access from the app to this data.

Finally, this is the call from the activity to start getting my location:

```
MyLocation myLocation;
myLocation = new MyLocation(this);
myLocation.getLocation();
scheduleUpdates(30);
```

In this case, I just set one alarm 30 seconds after the instant that I do, but this behavior is easy to program alarms to repeat any number of times. 
And this is the method that I use to stablish an alarm that wakes up the system even when the app is closed:

```
private void scheduleUpdates(int when){  
Log.d("CreateGroupFormActivity", "Alarm");
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);  

Intent intent  = new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class);  
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, MyConstants.ALARM_REQUEST_CODE, intent,  PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);  
manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + when * 1000, pIntent);       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, (I believe) you implicitly registered a receiver in [`requestLocationUpdates`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener%29):

```
locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, UPDATE_TIME, 0, locListener);
```

You should later call [`removeUpdates`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#removeUpdates%28android.location.LocationListener%29):

```
locManager.removeUpdates(locListener);
```

Comment: Ok, but if I need this app to be working on background and periodically get the location, I can't remove the updates, can I?. I have read something about using PASSIVE_PROVIDER instead of NETWORK_PROVIDER for the background work, but then I never get the updates.

Comment: Run it in something like `onDestroy`. This will be called only when your *service* "is no longer used and is being removed".

Comment: Finally I solved the problem using Alarms instead of Services. This helped me a lot: http://www.carlos-garcia.es/tutoriales/android-alarmas-alarmmanager.php Anyway, thank you very much for your response @Eric

Comment: @nutshell No problem. You may want to post your eventual solution as an answer, then accept it (when you can, I think you have to wait 2 days or so).

Comment: It's done :) In fact, it says that I have to wait until tomorrow to accept my own solution. Thank you again @Eric